# I am getting Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object, When I try to create more than 250 threads in my web application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Connection Pool Exception: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7277760/connection-pool-exception-cannot-get-a-connection-pool-error-timeout-waiting-f)

I am getting Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object error, When I try to create more than 250 threads in my web application. I am creating web application using JSF 2.0 and Hibernate.

I have tried with modified hibernate.xml,server.xml,context.xml and also mysql properties.

**The followings are I am getting.**

```
WARN (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:233) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
ERROR (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:234) - Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
ERROR (BaseServlet.java:301) - ******** java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1426)
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:140)
    org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:128)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:52)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:449)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor378.invoke(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor378.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1144)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1044)
    org.hibernate.connection.DatasourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProvider.java:92)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.openConnection(ConnectionManager.java:446)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.getConnection(ConnectionManager.java:167)
    org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.connection(JDBCContext.java:160)
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.begin(JDBCTransaction.java:81)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.beginTransaction(SessionImpl.java:1473)
    sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor378.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Please if have any idea about this help me......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you have set a timeout for **"dead"** connections and some queries take **longer** than that. That means that your **pool removed a busy connection** as "dead" from the pool and requests another from the **DB** - until the DB pulls the plug.

To debug this, **enable logging** for your connection pool, so you can see when it requests new connections.

also check your **mysql** connection settings. and try to **close connection** when you are done with your **db** coz next time(beyond `maxConnectionAge` limit) that connection state will be **dead** .

Comment: hi harmeet thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi Thanks my problem fixed by changes in context.xml file

I have changed followings properties in context.xml.file 

maxActive="-1" maxIdle="-1" maxWait="-1"

-1 means NO Limit.

Comment: @Ganesh please post your answer, if you have solved it yourself ortherwise mark as accepted whichever answer helped you. good luck :)

Comment: @Ganesh one thing you should not do this, it will make your connections sleep, as i have suggested open connection work close connection

Comment: This issues was happening by a protocol time delay. I debugged and solved that protocol issues after that i am not getting that exception.

Comment: The connections are open and close as u said.

Comment: @Ganesh set xml values to default there is no need to do that.if u are open and closing connection properly..

Answer (score 4):

I had such issue before, what you need to do is
`close hibernate sessions when you are done with it.`

e.g.

```
Session sess = factory.openSession();
 Transaction tx;
 try {
     tx = sess.beginTransaction();
     //do some work
     ...
     tx.commit();
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
     throw e;
 }
 finally {
     sess.close(); // closing session
 }
```