# Using Spring+Hibernate threw exception because of session

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

When the application starts, it works fine, but after many update operations, it throws an exception:

> [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection] with root cause  java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout
>   waiting for idle object

[image]

```
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}

public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;

}

protected  Session openSession() {
    return getSessionFactory().openSession();
}

 public void deleteAnyType(T t){
    Session session =super.openSession();
    session.delete(t);
    session.beginTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Comment: this question might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11734808/i-am-getting-cannot-get-a-connection-pool-error-timeout-waiting-for-idle-object

Comment: Don't use `openSession` use `getCurrentSession` and let spring manage the resources for you.

Comment: Please post the actual stack trace as text instead of screenshots. Others can't copy and paste from your images. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Comment: thank you for your help,it's my first time to use StackOverFlow,and forgive my pool English