# Solving Timeout Issue with Azure Synapse/ADF Pipeline of Pipelines

Tags: azure, timeout, azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

##### Context

We're creating a pipeline of Spark Jobs in Azure Synapse (much like in Azure Data Factory) that read in data from various databases and merge it into a larger dataset. Originally, we had a single pipeline that worked, with many Spark Jobs leading into others. As part of a redesign, we were thinking that we would create a pipeline for *each* individual Spark job, so that we can create various orchestration pipelines. If the definition of a Spark job changes, we only have to change the definition file in one place.

##### Problem

When we run our "pipeline of pipelines", we get an error that we don't get with the single pipeline. The error:

- Is a series of timeout errors like: `Timeout waiting for idle object`
- Occurs in different areas of the pipeline on different runs

This results in the failure of the pipeline as a whole.

##### Questions

1. What is the issue happening here?
2. Is there a setting that could help solve it? (Azure Synapse does not provide many levers)
3. Is our pipeline-of-pipelines construction an anti-pattern? (Doesn't seem like it should be since Azure allows it)

##### Hypotheses

From the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20401254/i-am-getting-pool-error-timeout-waiting-for-idle-object/20403406): are we running out of available connections in Azure? (how would you solve that?)

Comment: Not sure it is related, but are the Execute Pipeline activities flagged as "Wait on Completion", or are they all running in parallel?

Comment: Could you please share exactly which activity giving error along with error screenshot. Are you using execute pipeline activities inside master pipeline?
Could you please check box inside execute pipeline activity for filed "wait on completon"